# Using topology to solve basic analysis question

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)$ exist. Prove $f$ is uniformly countinous on $\mathbb{R}$.

This question can be solved by $\epsilon - \delta$, but I want to solve it only by topology.

1.Consider order topology in $\mathbb{\overline{R}}$, since $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)$ exist, so we know function $F$ defined by $F(\infty)=\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x), F(-\infty)=\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)$ is also continuous on $\mathbb{\overline{R}}$.

2.The order topology in $\mathbb{\overline{R}}$ is compact and metrizable [(extend real line)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Order_and_topological_properties), we denote this metric is $d'$.

3.$F$ is continuous on $\mathbb{\overline{R}}$ and $\mathbb{\overline{R}}$ is compact, so we know $F$ is uniformly continous.

4.Restrict $F$ on $\mathbb{R}$, then we know $f$ is uniformly continuous on  $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to metric $d'$.

I do not know how to figure it out here, because we want to prove $f$ is uniformly continuous on  $\mathbb{R}$ with respect metric $d$ (Euclidean metric).

Can you help me how to solve it by topology, thank you.

Comment: $d$ and $d'$ cannot be strongly equivalent on ${\bf R}$, because $d$ is complete while $d'$ is not.

Comment: uniform continuity is not a "topological" notion, but a "uniformity" one. So just topology won't help much.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  uniform continuity can be generalized to uniform space https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Uniform_continuity#Generalization_to_uniform_spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot embed $\mathbb{R}$ into a compact metric space $(X,d)$ such that $d$ restricted to $\mathbb{R}$ is the original Euclidean metric. And this seems needed to conclude from uniform continuity on $X$ the same on the reals.
This is shown by the sequence $x_n = n$, which would have a convergent subsequence to some $p \in X$, so would be Cauchy in $X$, hence also in the reals, contradiction. So I don't see how a compactification can give us uniform continuity on the reals. (This also works for uniform spaces, with the same argument.)
It is true that every metric space $X$  has a compactification that allows us to extend all already uniformly continuous real functions on $X$ to that compactification, see [this paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm147/fm14714.pdf), e.g. But this begs the question (We already need to know the original function is uniformly continuous). I see no general principle we could use easily.